# python - bs4 grab only certain links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<a title="dynamic link" href="test.php">text</a>
```

How can I grab the only the ones that have the title tag like the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use `select` method with commonly-used css selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <a title="dynamic link" href="test1.php">text</a>
...         <a href="test2.php">text</a>
...     </body>
... </html>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.select('a[title]')
[<a href="test1.php" title="dynamic link">text</a>]
```